# Node-RED function and multiple outputs

Tags: function, node-red

at the moment I've a little problem with one function. I'll create a function as switch. But I can't see that I route the msg block to the right output.

```
payloadJSON = JSON.parse(msg.payload, (key, value)=> {
  if(key == "changeType") {
    if (value === "create" ) {
        node.error('In: ' + value);
        return [ msg, null, null, null ];
    }else if(value === "update" ) {
        node.error('In: ' + value);
        return [ null, msg, null, null ];
    }else if(value === "delete" ) {
        node.error('In: ' + value);
        return [ null, null, msg, null ];
    }else{
        node.error('In: ' + "otherwise");
        return [ null, null, null, msg ];
    }
  }
});
```

Yes I configure 4 Outputs in the function

I can see the node.error message in the log, but I can't see any Output from the attached Debug Output .

Answer (score 3):

Your return statements are inside the function you've passed to the `JSON.parse` call - so they are not returning anything to Node-RED.

You need to use `node.send([msg,null ... ]);` in place of those return statements.